# How to setup VSCode to show typescript error inline

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to migrate an ES6 project to typescript. This is my first attempt at writing a typescript module in NodeJS.

It seems to work better in Angular-CLI so far.

I've got it compiling using command line `tsc`, but I'm not sure how to display errors and intellisense in the code editor?

In a directory I have the two files shown below. When it compiles it, as expected throws a compile error: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of cal
l target.`. This is fine.

But VSCode is not showing any errors in the editor, even if I make a deliberate syntax error like taking out a bracket, or type errors like this one. How do I  get VSCode to show inline syntax or compiler errors in the editor for .ts files?

**validation-error.ts**

```
/**
 * Wrapper for a particular validation error.
 */
export class ValidationError extends Error {
  private type: string;

  constructor(error: any) {
    super(error);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    this.message = error.message;
    this.type = 'ValidationError';
  }
}
```

Then I'm trying to write  simple spec to test out the workflow:

**validation-error.spec.ts**

```
import { ValidationError } from './validation-error';
import * as should from 'should';

describe('Validation Error', () => {
  it('should create a new instance', () => {
    const instance = new ValidationError();
    should.exist(instance);
  });
});
```

## Edited Here:

I'm still plugging away at this - I've setup `tsc` to run automatically with this job in `tasks.json`:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "taskName": "tsc",
  "command": "tsc",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
  "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
  "echoCommand": true
}
```

I suspect that if the errors were reported properly using `$tsc-watch`, the error would probably also show up in the editor. When I run the task I get output like:

```
running command$ tsc -w -p .
src/hello.ts(15,1): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
4:24:40 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

But there are no problems reported in the `Problems` view - even though clearly there's a compiler issue.

Got the `$tsc-watch` setting from this page of the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file in your project (opened directory) ?

Comment: I do have it already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even without having installed TypeScript locally or globally, the following setup provides inline errors.

```
C:/temp
  index.ts
  tsconfig.json
```

index.ts

```
let x: number;
x = "foo";
```

tsconfig.json

```
{ }
```

Here is a screenshot that shows the inline error in `x`.

[image]

Please try that setup and report back on what happens.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why mine was not working, I copied `tsconfig` from somewhere so perhaps there's some version issues or something. I eventually did get it working yesterday anyway with the tsc problem resolver - at least I think that's why it worked. It seemed to be a bug where on first compile it wasn't listing the errors in VS Code, but if I changed a file while it's in watch mode, then the errors were displayed as expected. So it's probably just an error in some combination of things in my setup.

Comment: An empty tsconfig.json? I doubt this is a working solution.

Answer (score 79):

For me the problem was resolved by setting **Typescript validation** to true in VSCode settings:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": true,
```

I had turned this off in my workspace settings in the past and forgot!

So make sure to double check that this setting is not set to false in your **user settings, workspace settings or folder settings**.

[image]

For instance the rule I was trying to get work was checking for undefined variables which was immediately fixed when I set validate to true.

[image]

Comment: "I had turned this off in my workspace settings in the past and forgot!". hahaha omg... i want my 5 hours back. . Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

I ran aground with this issue, managed to solve it by adding `"typescript.validate.enable": true` to my local settings.json file in the .vscode directory. My settings tell me that the typescript validator is enabled for VS code globally, but I wasn't able to see inline TS errors until I added the local settings file.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers (most before year 2020) did not work for me.

According to this [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953) in Microsoft's VS Code repository, do the following steps:

1. In your settings.json add:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": true,
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true,
```

2. In your tsconfig.json add:

```
"include": [
    "src",
    "global.d.ts",
  ],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "plugins",
    "public"
  ]
```

Wait a while (or restart VS Code) in order to see a list of errors shown in the open files and added in the problems panel.

Answer (score 2):

I just closed & restarted my VS Code and it started showing typescript errors like before.

If this doesn't work, I'd suggest restarting your computer system.

Comment: You can also issue the "Restart TS Server" command to just restart the piece that shows you errors.

Answer (score -2):

1.Edit in **setting.json**

```
"editor.hover.enabled": true
```

2.Settings > TypeScript › Validate: **Enable**